# Applying Cauchy-Riemann to $f(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

$$\ln|z|+i\text{Arg}(z)$$

the problem states that I have to apply Cauchy Riemann to the problem and determine a conclusion. Below is how far I got, but I'm not sure how to take the derivative of $\arctan(y/x)$. Plus, the point of using C-R is to separate the real and imaginary parts, but how would I do that when there is an $i$ inside of the natural log function? There is no identity to simplify it.

**My attempt**:

$$\ln|z|+i\text{Arg}(z)$$
$$\ln|x+iy|+i\arctan(y/x)$$

Comment: $|x+iy| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The derivative of $\arctan(x)$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams ok so I figured out that the C-R equations hold. I want to write that $f'(z)$ exists at all $z$, except $z \le 0$, would that be valid?